# 3 ways to flatten a list of lists. Is there a reason to prefer one of them?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assume we have a list as follows. `CoreResult` has a field of type `List<Double>`.

```
final List<CoreResult> list = new LinkedList<>(SOME_DATA);
```

The objective is to flatten the list after extracting that specific field from each `CoreResult` object.
Here are 3 possible options. Is any one of them preferable to the others?

**Option 1**: extract a field via `map()` and flatten inside collector

```
final List<Double> A = list.stream().map(CoreResult::getField)
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll);
```

**Option 2**: extract a field via `map()`, flatten via `flatMap()`, simple collector

```
final List<Double> B = list.stream().map(CoreResult::getField)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Option 3**: extract a field and flatten in one go via `flatMap()`, simple collector

```
final List<Double> C = list.stream().flatMap(
             x -> x.getField().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Would the answer be different if there was no need to extract any field from CoreResult, and instead one wanted to simply flatten a `List<List<Double>>`?

Comment: If you care for performance, you should not use `LinkedList`. And since `SOME_DATA` must already be a collection, there’s no sense in copying it into another `List`. So the preferred way is `SOME_DATA.stream(). /* whatever of the three options you like */`…

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm not sure about the performance of each one, but an important aspect of the builder pattern utilized by java streams is that it allows for **readability**. I personally find the option 2 to be the most readable. Option 3 is good, too. I would avoid option one because it kind of "cheats" the flattening of the collection.

Put each method on its own line and determine which is the most intuitive to read. I rather like the second one:

```
final List<Double> B = list.stream()
                           .map(CoreResult::getField)
                           .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I am getting "not-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" compilation error on .flatMap(List::stream) line

Answer (score 8):

I would go for option 2 or 3. If you want to flatten a `List<List<Double>>`, you would do this:

```
List<Double> list = doubleList.stream()
                              .flatMap(List::stream)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 and 2 is same, so up to you if you want to map first and then flat map or just flatmap.

With option 1 you have to open another stream to perform further operations.